# Autosize input/textbox width to width of its value using CSS

Tags: css, webkit

I'd like to have a textbox (input) which will auto size to the width of its text and grow as text is entered. I know I could do this using some JavaScript but is a CSS only approach possible?

I'm only particularly interested in supporting recent versions of Chrome (14/15) but would welcome hearing about other browsers.

Comment: I noticed that you had asked this question like a trillion years ago; did you ever end up figuring this out? Would really appreciate if you are able to get back, even if it's a no.

Comment: even after trillion years, this is not possible as of Oct 26, 2012...however simple javascript function can do. Very detailed explanation here: http://markos.gaivo.net/blog/?p=198